# How to import or include a javascript file in a gulp file

Tags: gulp

How can I import or include my own javascript file into a gulpfile?

Gulp is installed via npm, so I can include other npm modules like this:

```
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
```

So I would like to do something like:

```
var karmaConfig = require('karma-config.js');
```

The directory structure is like this:

```
node_modules/
gulpfile.js
package.json
karma-config.js
```

so the gulpfile is at the same level as the file that I want to import.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by:

```
var karmaConfig = require('./karma-config');
```

And whatever this file exports can now be accessed from `karmaConfig`.

hendrikswan is right that you can leave off from the end `.js` as that's the default. But you don't need to.

The `./` part means that it should be found from the current folder rather than in node_modules. If your structure was like this:

```
node_modules/
gulpfile.js
package.json
config/karma.js
```

You would require it thus:

```
var karmaConfig = require('./config/karma');
```